# ArithmeticProgression run infinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am following the Chapter 14 Control Flow of book Fluent Python,
encounter trouble with the following code:

```
class ArithmeticProgression:

    def __init__(self, begin, step, end=None):
        self.begin = begin
        self.step = step
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        result = type(self.begin + self.step)(self.begin)
        forever = self.end is None
        index = 0
        while forever or result < self.end:
            yield result
            index = + 1
            result = self.begin + self.step * index
```

When I test it according to the book:

```
In [220]: ap = ArithmeticProgression(1, 1, 5)

In [221]: ap
Out[221]: <__main__.ArithmeticProgression at 0x1098b2160>

In [222]: list(ap)


#it run endless not return any result
#I should Ctrl+C to break it mandatory
```

I check my code with the source code line by line [example-code/aritprog_v1.py at master · fluentpython/example-code](https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/14-it-generator/aritprog_v1.py)
but fail to find any problem.

Comment: Be careful when your `end` is `None` because it will also run infinitely when you iterate over it - by calling `list()` like you did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
index = + 1
```

should be

```
index += 1
```

Which will add one to `index` every iteration.  As is, this is `index = +1` or `index = 1`.  So the value of `result` never changes between loops.